# Convert list of values to a key value json

Tags: json, powershell, key, key-value-store

I'm trying to convert a list comma separated  IP values (192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3, xxxx,xxxx) to a key value json so that at the end of all I can have a file with the structure below.

```json
 {
    "ips": [
        {
            "ip": "192.168.1.1"
        },
        {
            "ip": "192.*.*.*"
        },
        {
            "ip": "192.168.1.3/32"
        }
    ]
}
```

I was trying to user the command ConvertTo-Json command form powershell but really don't manage how to get it.

Home anyone can give me a hand and guide me how to handle this issue

Thanks you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create objects or hashtables with the same contents and structure as your desired JSON, then pipe to `ConvertTo-Json`:

```
@{
    'ips' = @(
        @{ "ip" = "192.168.1.1" },
        @{ "ip" = "192.*.*.*" },
        @{ "ip" = "192.168.1.3/32" },
    )
} |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content path\to\output.json
```

Now you just need to generate the inner hashtables from a list instead of hardcoding them:

```
$listOfIPs = '192.168.1.1,192.*.*.*,192.168.1.3/32' -split ','

@{
    'ips' = @(
        $listOfIPs |ForEach-Object { @{ "ip" = $_ } }
    )
} |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content path\to\output.json
```

Comment: Followed your suggestion and it works just perfect, thank so much